# How to convert a Date from database into formatted string while returning a List

Tags: android, sqlite, string-formatting, android-room, date

Is there a way to format a Date in a database while it is being returned in a list? I currently have a database that holds an EntityScore. It includes a Date. When I query the database to return a particular list, I want to retrieve the date as a formatted string.

Accessing database:

```
val list: ArrayList<List<ScoresReport>> = arrayListOf()

for(i in 0 until listHeadings.size)
    list.add(databasePersons.daoScores().getScoresDayPI(listHeadings[i].ID))
```

daoScores:

```
@Query("SELECT date as text, AVG(score) as score FROM ScoresTable WHERE personID =:personID")
    fun getScoresDayPI(personID: Int) : List<ScoresReport>
```

ScoresReport:

```
class ScoresReport(var text: String, var score: Int)
{}
```

When I access the database to return the Date as text in the list, it appears in its milliseconds from 1970 form. I want it to format the Date as text but in a pattern that may change based on user's settings. For example, the user can select which pattern they want their date to appear.

This is what I want:

```
@Query("SELECT date as SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date) -> text, AVG(score) as score FROM ScoresTable WHERE personID =:personID")
    fun getScoresDayPI(personID: Int) : List<ScoresReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to use a `TypeConverter` as described in [this post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-time-2b4cf9672b98) by Chris Banes (I just converted it to Kotlin)

```
object DateConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun fromMillisToDate(millis: Long?): Date? {
        return millis?.let {
            return Date(millis)
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun fromDateToMillis(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time
    }
}
```

And then you need to register this into your `Room` database instance using `TypeConverters` annotation to make it to apply to all your `Date` objects in the database.

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        User::class,
        Todo::class,
    ],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(value = [DateConverter::class])
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    abstract fun todoDao(): TodoDao
}
```

> Remember that using `Date` for storing dates or timestamp is bad
>   practice if you need to consider timezones. If you are in this case
>   it's better if you use `OffsetDateTime` objects and there are all the
>   necessary step to do in the Chris post

Comment: I already have a TypeConverter that converts the date to a long and vice versa. What I need is a way to format the date into a string on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to interpret the pattern and come up with a format string similar to the hardcoded one below, but this should give you a shot at the proper syntax.

Try changing it to this:

```
@Query("SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', date) as scoredate, AVG(score) as score FROM ScoresTable 
WHERE personID =:personID")
```

Or try:

```
@Query("SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', date, unixepoch) as scoredate, AVG(score) as score FROM ScoresTable 
WHERE personID =:personID")
```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: This seems to be usable as a solution but for some reason I am getting a weird return: SELECT strftime('%m-%d-%Y', date) as text returns "11-24--471" when it should be "04-14-2019." Could it have something to do with my typeconverters?

Comment: That is strange.  I checked the date format parameters and they look to be the correct syntax as per this page:  https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/strftime.php  Do you know what version of SQLite you have?  And would your system have any alternate date/time settings?

Comment: I think it may be because my TypeConverter converts a date to a long so when it retrieves the date, it is actually retrieving a long and then trying to format that when the format should be a string. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the SQLite column defined as TEXT or Integer?  Check out this link:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html  it mentions a modifier called unixepoch that is used to interpret dates stored as Integers.  Not sure what will happen if you store an Integer date in a TEXT column though.